# Convert number from input with/without separators to whole number

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I am trying to allow only `[0-9]`, `.`, and `,` from being input, as I only want the user to be able to input numbers with and without separators. These are the tests I want to allow:

```
1000 == 1.000,00
1000 == 1,000.00
1000 == 1.000
1000 == 1,000
1000 == 1000
```

How users type these is completely up to them and what they usually do. I want to check if what the user inputs is equal to `1000`.

https://jsfiddle.net/m2pq06b1/

What is the best way to do this? I need all cases above to be true.

Comment: Please let me know why this was downvoted.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but basically this is guess-work. Without knowing the locale, how would you be able to know whether `1.003` is one thousand and three, or one and three thousands?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It's common that if you type three numbers after a separator, it means thousand. It's quite common. When you only type two, it generally means cents or hundredths of a whole (basically 1-99).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> It's common that if you type three numbers after a separator, it means
>   thousand. It's quite common. When you only type two, it generally
>   means cents or hundredths of a whole (basically 1-99).

Based on that, I propose the following solution:

1. Replace all separators (`,` and `.`) followed by exactly two digits and the end of the string with a decimal point.
2. Remove all separators not followed by exactly two digits and the end of the string.
3. Parse the sanitized value to a number using `parseFloat()`.

```js
var values = ["1.000,00", "1,000.00", "1.000", "1,000","1000"];

values.forEach(value => {
  let sanitized = value.replace(/[.,](?=\d{2}$)/g, '.').replace(/[.,](?!\d{2}$)/g, '');
  let number = parseFloat(sanitized);
  
  console.log(number == 1000);
});
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty good solution to be honest. Only exception is something like `1,000,00` is generally not good. One would normally think that means `1`. I think the common rule is "You can either use comma or dot as separator", meaning `1,000,00` isn't technically a correctly formatted number.

Comment: I can't think a any number parser that would allow `1,000,00`, even with the locale being specified.

Comment: Exactly. I can't find the best way to do this, so it doesn't confuse the user at all. Right now checking whether the user's input is `>= 1000`. If the user types `1.000,000` I'm guessing the correct number is `1000`, right? Since you're basically trying to separate thousandths using two separators, which technically is illegal.

Comment: The best way to do this, in my opinion, is to get the user's locale (either from some sort of user profile you might have, or directly from the browser itself), and parse the number according to the user's locale. For `1.000,000', both one thousand and one million are correct, depending on the locale.

Comment: I want to support all the inputs, though. My locale is set to en-US even though I'm really da-DK (I prefer English). I don't want to limit the users to either one.

Comment: In that case, if your rule of two digits means cents or hundreds no longer holds, there's no way of knowing which is which.

Comment: The rule basically says "Two digits means hundreds and you are only allowed to use one separator for thousands". `1.000,000` would be `1000` in my eyes. `1,000,000` is a million. `1,000,000.000` is still a million.